# How can I make a property of a ViewModel created in the constructor of one view accessible to another view created in a ContentPresenter?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, contentpresenter

I am writing a C# application using the MVVM (Model, View, View-Model) design pattern.

I have a `UserControl` called ucDesigner. This is the only `UserControl` inside the main window. The following code is the definition of the constructor of the ucDesigner from the file ucDesigner.xaml.cs:

```
public ucDesigner()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DesignerViewModel designerVM = new DesignerViewModel();
    DataContext = designerVM;
}
```

This code above creates a new DesignerViewModel and sets it as the `DataContext` of the ucDesigner view.

The following code is the definition of the DesignerViewModel:

```
public class DesignerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DrawViewModel DrawVM { get; set; }

    public ToolboxViewModel ToolboxVM { get; set; }

    public DesignerViewModel()
    {
        DrawVM = new DrawViewModel();
        ToolboxVM = new ToolboxViewModel();
    }
}
```

The constructor of the DesignerViewModel creates a new DrawViewModel and assigns it as the value of the DrawVM property in the DesignerViewModel.

ucDesigner has a `ContentPresenter` with a `DataTemplate` which displays a ucDraw view (of type UserControl). The following code is from ucDesigner.xaml:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Name="DrawingArea" Content="{Binding DrawVM}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DrawViewModel}">
            <uc:ucDraw />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

I want the instance of the DrawViewModel (called DrawVM) from the DesignerViewModel created in the ucDesigner constructor to be accessible to the ucDraw view that is created with the `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: You will find DrawVM in `DataContext` of ucDraw.

Comment: @LPL So how do I set the `DataContext` of ucDraw, since it is displayed with a `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: It is already set because you assign ucDraw to all instances of type DrawViewModel and WPF will set the DataContext for you.

Comment: @LPL Ok, so I was trying to set the `DataContext` of the ucDraw in its constructor. Evidently, the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` is set automatically, but not until after the execution of its constructor (what was I thinking?). So I have now added `((DrawViewModel)(DataContext)).PopulateComponents(this);` to the `Loaded` event handler and it works fine.